# Why Javascript is not getting called after console.log

Tags: javascript, typeof

I am trying to create a function which console.log object or an array type

```
function whichDataStructure (ITEM){

     if (typeof  ITEM ==='object'){
        console.log ('I am object');
   } if (typeof  ITEM === 'array') {
    console.log ('i am array');

   } else {
    console.log(' neither');


  }
};
```

Answer (score 1):

In Javascript [Arrays](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/Array) are actually a kind of Object.

You have to use the [`Array.isArray()`](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/Array/isArray) function to find out if a value is an Array:

```
function whichDataStructure(item) {
    if (Array.isArray(item)) {
        console.log('I am an Array');
    } else if (typeof item === 'object'){
        console.log('I am an Object');
    } else {
        console.log('I am of type: ' + typeof item);
    }
};
```

It is important that you test if the value is an Array *before* testing if it is an Object. Otherwise it will always be seen as an Object.